# Close childForm when Open a New childForm in MDI Parent?

Tags: c#

I have a treeView to open each child Form, but when I open new child form I can still see the previous child form behind the new child form. What I want to do is close the old child form when open a new one. **(childForm.Close();   // not working somehow)**

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedNodeText = e.Node.Text;
    Form1 myform1 = new Form1();
    Form2 myform2 = new Form2();

    if (selectedNodeText == "1")
    {
        myform1.MdiParent = this;
        myform1.Parent = this.splitContainer1.Panel2;                        
        myform1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(myform1);
        myform1.BringToFront();
        myform1.Show();
    }
    if (selectedNodeText == "2")
    {
        myform2.MdiParent = this;
        myform2.Parent = this.splitContainer1.Panel2;                        
        myform2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(myform2);
        myform2.BringToFront();
        myform2.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the second time today that somebody is trying to put a toplevel window into a panel.  It still won't work.

Comment: I think that is a side question although a very relevant remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [MdiChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your form object. There is a reference to all forms you attached to your MdiContainer.

Another way is to store the reference to your forms in the class itself and close the old one if you open another:

```
private Form1 myform1 = null;
private Form2 myform2 = null;

private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
   string selectedNodeText = e.Node.Text;

   if (selectedNodeText == "1" && myform1 == null) {
       myform1 = new Form1()
       // ... some code ...
       if (myform2 != null) {
           myform2.Close();
           myform2 = null;
       }
   }
   if (selectedNodeText == "2" && myform2 == null) {
       myform2 = new Form2()
       // ... some code ...
       if (myform1 != null) {
           myform1.Close();
           myform1 = null;
       }
   }
}
```